# No inserta registros en mysql

Tags: php, java, mysql, android

Buen dia, tengo esta parte de código para realizar inserción en una base de datos mysql con php:

```
Response.Listener<String> respoListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                            boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

                            if (success) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(Register.this, Loginenglish.class);
                                Register.this.startActivity(intent);

                            } else {
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Register.this);
                                builder.setMessage(R.string.errorreg)
                                        .setNegativeButton(R.string.retry, null)
                                        .create().show();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }//fin de método onResponse
                };//fin de Responde:listener
                RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(name, user, passwd, date, email, respoListener);
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Register.this);
                queue.add(registerRequest);
```

He hecho debug en la linea donde dice boolean success y este responde success, el problema es que cuando reviso la base de datos no aparece ningún registro insertado.

En el logcat aparece:

```
04-29 20:06:01.710 5701-5802/matgic.com.matgic E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0xb7d49dc0 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0x9ffabddc arg=0x0
04-29 20:06:01.711 5701-5802/matgic.com.matgic E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0xb7d49dc0 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_RSA
E/NativeCrypto: Unknown error during handshake
E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb7f69810
```

Comment: ¿Mandas los datos al servidor aquí: `RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(name, user, passwd, date, email, respoListener);` ? ¿Verificaste en el servidor que los datos se están recibiendo bien y que no hay errores allí o claves duplicadas o cosas así? Lo que muestras del Logcat no parece tener nada que ver con la petición en sí. ¿Tu petición no maneja los errores de la petición misma? Sería bueno ponerle un manejo de errores y hacer debug también allí para ver si la petición en sí está fallando.

Comment: si, ahi donde dices mando los datos al servidor, la verdad aún no he verificado eso en el servidor que los datos se esten recibiendo bien alguna idea de como puedo hacer eso? de antemano mil gracias por tu ayuda A. cedano